# One word for 'Person being evaluated'

Tags: single-word-requests

I am developing a software application for a Medical Committee which will analyse [medical] examination results and issue certificates based on them. The Committee never sees the person and the exam results may be years old, so 'patient' is not a good term.

What can I call the person who is being evaluated? In Spanish they use *Evaluado* which may be 'Evaluated' or 'Evaluee' but I don't know which to use or if they are correct.

It would be great to use a single word, not a phrase like 'Person being evaluated'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A term used for the person being evaluated in many scientific and medical studies is *[subject](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/subject)*

> a person or thing that undergoes experiment, analysis, treatment, etc

Comment: I also found this [forum thread](http://bbs.cdisc.org/bbs/forums/thread-view.asp?tid=3351) which links to a [FDA.gov document](http://www.fda.gov/downloads/Drugs/GuidanceComplianceRegulatoryInformation/Guidances/UCM073122.pdf). They mention 'patient' 7 times and 'subject' 265 times, so I think I'm about to accept this.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest *Patient* is exactly the right term. The person **was** a patient at the time the original examination was performed.

*Evaluee* is a possibility, but it seems rather impersonal. The Committee is dealing with results from real people.

Comment: I agree.  I was just about to post that Patient would be the proper term.  The only other thing that would come to mind is customer.

Comment: Uhmm.. Yes but they were not their patients and they do treat them as impersonal subject, so it would be closer to their needs.

Comment: *Customer* might imply that they are paying for a service (and have a choice about doing that). *Client* could be an option, but *patient* happily covers even those who have died in the meantime. @aldo: I would say that it doesn't matter **whose** patient the patient was.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks for appreciation. I think it matters because commitee is not examining people, but exams results. The person was a 'patient' on the clinic, but is a 'evaluee' or 'subject' on Commitee (which is third-party). I would like to reflect this, too. In addition, if they are dead, they won't be evaluated by Commitee.

Answer (score 1):

An evaluee is usually used in flight related duties i.e. in the military. In the U.S. Navy we use this term for people getting an evaluation on their crew position - enlisted or officer (pilot, gunner and etc.)/

Answer (score -1):

how about ***Examinee***?

it's a fairly neutral term.